# Why my graphql implementation returns "undefined" after executed in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, apollo-client

what I am trying is to fetch some data on the page load, and then use a part of the fetched data to fetch another piece of data and display. Thanks in advance for your time.

**The Problem**

As I added my code below, I need to use *getFirstResults()* and *getSecondResults()* two times in the component. First is in ngOnInit by calling them in *getData()* , second is in function which is triggered by a button.

The problem is here when I call the *getFirstResults()* and *getSecondResults()* in ngOnInit in any way, I receive "undefined" value when I call them in in *functionActivatedByButton()*.

If I remove *getFirstResults()* and *getSecondResults()* from ngOnInit, everything works perfect but I can't receive the data on page load.

**What I've tried so far**

*functionActivatedByButton()*

- Remove *getFirstResults()* and *getSecondResults()* from *getData()* and call them in ngOnInit

```
      ngOnInit(): void {
           this.getData();
           getFirstResults();
           getSecondResults();
         }
```

- Created child components and devide the calls.
- Created different queries and try to call one in ngoninit and the other one in

---

**Here is the code:**

```
     ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getData();
          }
```

```
private getData(): void {
    this.dataServiceOne
      .fetch(someParams)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.object = data;
        this.checkStatus(this.object.status);
        this.getFirstResults();
        this.getSecondResults();
      });   }
```

```
    private getFirstResults(): void{
        this.dataServiceTwo
          .fetch(someOtherParams)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
          .subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
              // do something
            } else {
              // do something else
            }
          });
      }
```

```
    private getSecondResults(): void{
        this.dataServiceThree
          .fetch(someOtherParams)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
          .subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
              // do something
            } else {
              // do something else
            }
          });
      }
```

```
    public functionActivatedByButton(): void {
        this.dataServiceFour
          .mutate(params)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
          .subscribe((result) => {
            if (result) {
              //do some stuff
              this.getFirstResults();
            } else {
              //do some other stuff
            }
          });
        this.dataServiceFive
          .mutate(params)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
          .subscribe((result) => {
            if (result) {
              //do some stuff
              this.getSecondResults();
            } else {
              //do some other stuff
            }
          });
      }
```